# How to set CORS header in an AJAX call with pure JavaScript that is hitting other rest service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cors

I am having following JS function that gets called on html page load. When the page loads I see following error in the Firefox console logs.

**Firefox Console Log:**

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/publicKey/lookup/TRUUS2"
TRUUS2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/publicKey/lookup/TRUUS2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

**publickey.js**

```
function loadPublicKey() {

    var xmlhttp = createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/publicKey/lookup/TRUUS2');
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("keyDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
}


function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return xhr;
}
```

I have already added `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` statement to fix the CORS issue but no luck. I am looking for pure JS implementation.

**Note:** I am able to hit the http://localhost:8080/publicKey/lookup/TRUUS2 URL successfully through Postman and getting the response as well. No issues there.

Not sure what am I missing. Please guide.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how CORS works. You don't put the header on the request - it needs to be on the *response*. You need to amend your server side code.

Comment: Thanks Rory, you were right. Updated this post with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input provided by Rory, I removed the `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` from the JS and added snippet `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8084")` in my controller and that solved the problem.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8084")
@RestController
public class PublicKeyLookupController {
    //code removed for brevity
}
```